# How to use jsPDF with angular 2

Tags: angular, jspdf, angular2-cli

**I got an Error: jsPDF is not defined , I am currenty using following code :**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import 'jspdf';
declare let jsPDF;
@Component({
  ....
  providers: [
    { provide: 'Window',  useValue: window }
  ]
})
export class GenratePdfComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject('Window') private window: Window,
    ) { }

  download() {

        var doc = jsPDF();
        doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
        doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');    
        doc.save('Test.pdf');
    }
}
```

**I have install npm of jsPDF but don't know how import jspdf and run with angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.17**

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**I have done it, after doing lot of R&D , their are few steps to follow as below :**
*Install :*

```
npm install jspdf --save

typings install dt~jspdf --global --save

npm install @types/jspdf --save
```

*Add following in angular-cli.json:*

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js" ]
```

*html:*

```
<button (click)="download()">download </button>
```

*component ts:*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: 'Window',  useValue: window }
  ]
})
export class GenratePdfComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject('Window') private window: Window,
    ) { }

  download() {

        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
        doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
        doc.addPage();
        doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

        // Save the PDF
        doc.save('Test.pdf');
    }
}
```

Comment: How would one do this with the addHTML function?

Comment: 'autoTable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'

Comment: Thanks! helped me a ton!

Comment: @FlorisdG automatically added on a new jsPDF()

Comment: Isnt `typings install dt~jspdf --global --save` deprecated? https://github.com/typings/typings#deprecation-notice-regarding-typescript20

Comment: you can add images,shapes,lines too. more details https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: `import jspdf from 'jspdf';` is the right command for importing jspdf now

Answer (score 11):

Old question but this is an alternative solution that I got up and running in my angular app. I ended up modifying [this jsPDF solution](https://github.com/MarouaneSH/Ionic-jsPdf-Html2Canvas) to work without using the ionic/cordova CLI.

```
npm install jspdf --save
npm install @types/jspdf --save
npm install html2canvas --save
npm install @types/html2canvas --save
```

Add an id to whichever div contains the content you want to generate the PDF

```
<div id="html2Pdf">your content here</div>
```

Import the libraries

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

Add the method for generating the PDF

```
generatePdf() {
    const div = document.getElementById("html2Pdf");
    const options = {background: "white", height: div.clientHeight, width: div.clientWidth};

    html2canvas(div, options).then((canvas) => {
        //Initialize JSPDF
        let doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
        //Converting canvas to Image
        let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/PNG");
        //Add image Canvas to PDF
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 20, 20);

        let pdfOutput = doc.output();
        // using ArrayBuffer will allow you to put image inside PDF
        let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(pdfOutput.length);
        let array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (let i = 0; i < pdfOutput.length; i++) {
            array[i] = pdfOutput.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        //Name of pdf
        const fileName = "example.pdf";

        // Make file
        doc.save(fileName);

    });
}
```

I found this solution worked well for my web app and was beneficial as I have control over when I want to generate the PDF (after receiving data asynchronously). As well, I didn't need install any libraries globally.

Comment: very Neat, worked for me, what you did for a high resolution pdf?

Comment: @Aarchie that's still an outstanding issue for me, haven't gotten back to it yet either. Will update if I find a solution. My guess is that this library is limited and I may need to use a different one

Answer (score 7):

I have created a jsPdf demo based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41499623) with help from **@gsmalhotra**

First install

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

I have used array of images, first converting the image to base64 **(jsPDF doesn't allow image URLs)**

```
getBase64Image(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  console.log("image");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  return dataURL;
}
```

Then in a loop, I have called above function which returns base64 image, and then added image to PDF using `doc.addImage()`.

```
for(var i=0;i<this.images.length;i++){
   let imageData= this.getBase64Image(document.getElementById('img'+i));
   doc.addImage(imageData, "JPG", 10, (i+1)*10, 180, 150);
   doc.addPage();
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let img of images;let i=index">
    <img id="img{{i}}" class="img-fluid" crossOrigin="Anonymous" [src]="img.url">
</div>
```

[Demo](https://angular5-pdf.stackblitz.io) 
[Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-pdf)

Comment: Hey, great edit! Thanks for taking the feedback and working with it. Good luck on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 4):

Here is how it should be for downloading a `div` in **Angular 11**:

1. Install npm package:

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

2. Add template ref in `html` as:

```
<div #myTemp>
   // other code here

  <button (click)="print()"></button>
</div>
```

2. Import in `xyz.component.ts`:

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

export class XYZComponent { 
   @ViewChild('myTemp') myTempRef: ElementRef;

   print(){
    const DATA = this.myTempRef.nativeElement;
    html2canvas(DATA).then(canvas => {        
      let fileWidth = 200;
      let fileHeight = canvas.height * fileWidth / canvas.width;
      
      const FILEURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
      let PDF = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      let position = 0;
      PDF.addImage(FILEURI, 'PNG', 5, 5, fileWidth, fileHeight)      
      PDF.save('angular-demo.pdf');
    });   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** install the package

```
    npm install jspdf
```

**2.** import it like follow

```
    import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf'
   // important! using this ES6 syntax you don't need to import the library via the script
      section in angular.json
```

**3.** use it

```
 // for somereadon the latest version (currenly 2.3)  words with properties 
   of type string only, even if you have dates or numbers, convert them to string first
 let data = [
   {
    id: "123032510",
    firstname: "Benzara Tahar",
    lastname: "Riad",
   },
   {
    loggedInUserId: "1233205",
    firstname: "Matouk",
    lastname: "Aymen",
   }
   ];
  let header = this.createHeaders(['ID', 'Firstname', 'Lastname']);
  let doc = new jsPDF()
  doc.table(1, 1, data, header, {})
  doc.save()
```