# Generate PDF angular 2 with jspdf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular2 with jspdf.

So first I installed jspdf:

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

I tried to do this:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
var Html="<h5>ORDERDETAILS</h5><p>ORDERNUMBER</p><table align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='600'><tr>  <td style='border: 1px solid #CCC;padding:10px;'><img src='###SITE_LOGO###' alt='Cracker Deals' width='110px'>  </td> </tr> ###ORDER_STATUS### <tr><td style='border-left:1px solid #CCC;border-right:1px solid #CCC;padding:15px;font-size:12px;'><div>Dear <strong> ###CUSTOMER_NAME### </strong></div><p>Thank You for your order. This mail has your order details <br>You can also view your Order Detials - <a href='###SITE_LINK###'>View Details</a></p><div><h3>Shipping Address</h3>###CUSTOMER_ADDRESS###</div></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#ffffff' style='padding: 15px;border: 1px solid #CCC;'>###CARTDETAILS###</td></tr><tr><td bgcolor='' align='center' style='border:1px solid #CCC; border-top:0;padding:10px;font-size:11px;'>CopyRights 2017 Cracker Deals</td></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#2874F0' style='height:10px;'></td></tr> </table>";
var doc = new jsPDF();
 doc.addHTML(Html, () => {
      doc.save('test.pdf');
 doc.save('Test.pdf');
})
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: You need either https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas or https://github.com/cburgmer/rasterizeHTML.js
```

How can I fix this issue.

I need to generate a PDF.

Kindly advice me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Generate pdf from HTML using jspdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276882/angular2-generate-pdf-from-html-using-jspdf)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put below code to index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

then

```
npm i jspdf --save
```

and

```
bower install jspdf --save
```

After these steps try your codes.

Comment: iT can be true but it is also dublicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276882/angular2-generate-pdf-from-html-using-jspdf?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.I try to this.getting this err Proxy must be used when rendering url

Comment: Without putting script in index.html can we do in any other way ?