# Printing a HTML template as PDF - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to use [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to print my HTML template as a PDF, but I get an error. How should I do it?

Let's say that I have this template:

```
<div style="text-align:center;" class="sub-header col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <span class="welcome-message col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">Hola mundo</span>
</div>
```

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, what I have used is this two links:

**1st link**
It is used to check how to install the needed library:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41484323/how-to-use-jspdf-with-angular-2)

npm install jspdf --save

npm install @types/jspdf --save

*angular-cli.json*

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js" ]
```

**2nd link**
Used as a model to developed the needed code (sorry but this answer is in Spanish)

[Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43641/crear-un-pdf-de-un-div-especifico-con-jspdf)

*Component TS*

```
  pruebaDivAPdf() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    var source = $('#imprimir')[0];

    var specialElementHandlers = {
      '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
        return true
      }
    };
    var margins = {
      top: 60,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 20,
      width: 522
    };

    pdf.fromHTML(
      source,
      margins.left, // x coord
      margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      },

      function (dispose) {
        pdf.save('Prueba.pdf');
      }, margins
    );
  }
```

*Component HTML*

```
<a (click)="pruebaDivAPdf()" class="button">Pasar a PDF</a>
```

Comment: Where do $('#imprimir')[0]; and '#bypassme' came from?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jsPDF.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41484323/how-to-use-jspdf-with-angular-2) using jsPDF.

After implementing jsPDF then you also need to install `html2Canvas`
and add it in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
"html2canvas": "0.5.0-beta4",
"@types/html2canvas": "0.5.32"
.........
}
```

Run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I have used jsPDF but the printed html was quite ugly so I have decided to create the table manualy.

Here is an example of the frame:

```
doc.setFontSize(22)
lineNumber = lineNumber - 6  // total number of mm in the table
doc.text(80, 20, 'Dayly tasks')  // Title
doc.setFontSize(12)   
doc.line(18, 30, 18, lineNumber)  //first vertical line
doc.line(192, 30, 192, lineNumber) //last vertical line
doc.line(18, lineNumber, 192, lineNumber)// last horizontal line
doc.line(18, 30, 192, 30) // first horizontal line
//drax inside the table
doc.line(18, 40, 192, 40)  // colon name
doc.line(42, 30, 42, lineNumber)  //col day
doc.line(172, 30, 172, lineNumber) // col activity
doc.line(152, 30, 152, lineNumber) // col duration
doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.text(20, 35, 'Date');
doc.text(70, 35, 'Activity Comment');
doc.text(154, 35, 'Duration');
doc.text(174, 35, 'Overtime')
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(180, 280, pageNumber + '')
```

Where `lineNumber` is firstly calculated.

with best regards