# Angular 8, using jspdf and autotable-jspdf import/usage issues

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

**Angular 8 - JSPDF & JSPDF-AutoTable**

I need to export/generate one pdf base one grid in html, but is necessary some DOM changes with css, remove some toggle button and change header etc, and all solutions I found has some flicks in print like the simple window.print(). I tried also pdfmake-wrapper and ngx-export-as, but they don't have the autoTable magic...and the last one the dom changes are ignored, except if I use the Renderer2 DOM manipulation...**but I need a solution with css class changes inject and no flick, so I get back the JSPDF.**

I installed jspdf and jspdf-autotable packages with npm.

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.2.4",
    ...
}
```

In angular-cli.json file, I have embedded the scripts:

```
"scripts": [ 
        "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
      ],
```

In my component.ts file , I have imported these files as follows:

```
 import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; 
 import * as autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable';
```

I have also tried these lines to import jspdf-autotable

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; 
import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

I have also tried another combination.

```
import jsPDF = require('jspdf');
import { autoTable as AutoTable } from 'jspdf-autotable';
```

**But nothing is working.**

// In My component.ts file I'm using sample code as follows:

```
let columns = ["ID", "Name", "Age", "City"];
var data = [
    [1, "Jonatan", 25, "Gothenburg"],
    [2, "Simon", 23, "Gothenburg"],
    [3, "Hanna", 21, "Stockholm"]
];
const doc = new jsPDF(); // or let doc = new jsPDF.default();
doc.autoTable(columns, data);
doc.save("filename");
```

But now when I run the node command to start app then during debug, I'm getting errors as:

a - Property 'autoTable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'.

b - Error TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof jsPDF'.

Any idea?

Comment: I found one partial solution with doc.table() [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2223)...generates the table....but the import jsPDF returns always errors, I tryed to send to automated building server, but returns that error 'default'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, but changing to another package, [PDFMaker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-maker).

Check all [documentation](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/) and [supported browsers](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/getting-started/client-side/supported-browsers/).

Checkout, there's a awesome [playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html#) and one [example in Angular 8](https://github.com/ngdevelop-tech/angular-8-export-pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Awesome. It works perfectly for my scenario too. jsPDF wasted a lot of my time with these errors. Their examples, what they had posted in github none of them work.

Comment: Found the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557043/7409460

Answer (score 5):

You have to use as following. I had the same question for a while, but after asking the question from the developers, I found that you have to use the instance of jsPdf() as an argument of autoTable() function. Rest goes as the [documentation](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html) of jsdpf.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable';

const doc = new jsPDF();

const columns = [['First Column', 'Second Column', 'Third Column']];
const data = [
['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3'],
['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3']
];

 autoTable(doc, {
      head: columns,
      body: data,
      didDrawPage: (dataArg) => { 
       doc.text('PAGE', dataArg.settings.margin.left, 10);
      }
 }); 

doc.save('table.pdf');
```

**Example**
*Source Codes*
https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-pine-wjp1g?file=/src/app/app.component.ts
*Live Demo*
https://wjp1g.csb.app/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you would want to do is do something like:

```
const jsPDF = require('jspdf');
```

or

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

This assumes that your node_modules has been configured as part of your path, but if you are using the CLI you should be good here.

Comment: Error...The first one require need node types, but importing like import jsPDF = require('jspdf');, the first and the second one returns error..."Property 'autoTable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'".

Comment: Have you tried the recommendation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41499623/605481

Comment: Basically they import the types. If getting the types doesn't help, I'd put a breakpoint in the code and see what does exist at execution time.

Comment: I try all combinations possible, and search for all possible examples. @nephiw I check already before the link you shared, there's an example with angular 5....but, with Angular 8 like my case no, using like that example I get the "error TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof jsPDF'."

Answer (score 0):

Use this example

```
var generateData = function (amount) {
    var result = [];
    var data =
    {
        coin: "100",
        game_group: "GameGroup",
        game_name: "XPTO2",
        game_version: "25",
        machine: "20485861",
        vlt: "0"
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < amount; i += 1) {
        data.id = (i + 1).toString();
        result.push(Object.assign({}, data));
    }
    return result;
};

function createHeaders(keys) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
        result.push({
        'id' : keys[i],
            'name': keys[i],
            'prompt': keys[i],
            'width': 65,
            'align': 'center',
            'padding': 0
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the issue is **not how to generate the table**...is how to import jsPDF and use as doc.autoTable(alloptions);....we used already jsPDF in AngularJS, but NOW with Angular 8, always returns a error, in my team we are migrating AngularJS to Angular 8 (Typescript), this is really the last one detail for all migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer respective to the question should be this. Posting if anyone needed this in future,

Refer
[https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable for autable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable)

U need to,

```
npm install jspdf jspdf-autotable
```

and es6,

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf'
import 'jspdf-autotable'

const doc = new jsPDF()
doc.autoTable({ html: '#my-table' })
doc.save('table.pdf')
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I dunno why some people keep on recommending this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is not because of the import. If you use doc.autoTable is the reason for the error.
The below worked for me and it is given in the official documentation as well.

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable';  

autoTable(doc, { html: '#report-per-depot',startY: 30, });
```

For different examples, https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js

Reference link: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable#installation

Excerpt from the above link:

You can also use the exported autoTable method. This works better with typescript and alternative jsPDF versions.

```
 import jsPDF from 'jspdf'
 // import jsPDF = require('jspdf') // // typescript without esModuleInterop flag
 // import jsPDF from 'yworks-pdf' // using yworks fork
 // import jsPDF from 'jspdf/dist/jspdf.node.debug' // for nodejs
 import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable'

 const doc = new jsPDF()
 autoTable(doc, { html: '#my-table' })
 doc.save('table.pdf')
```